# Rails Rspec allow multiple method call in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

```
desc 'Remove credential state users who no longer request for confirm otp within 10 minutes'
 task failed_user_cleaner: :environment do
 puts "Daily UserRecord Cleaning CronJob started - #{Time.now}"

 @user = User.with_state("credentials").with_last_otp_at(Time.now - 10.minutes)
 Users::Delete.new(@user).destroy_all

 puts "Daily UserRecord Cleaning CronJob ended - #{Time.now}"
end
```

Above is crop job rake file code.

then I've tried in many times and found in many times.
But I couldn't find the way to write unit test case for above job.

Help me to write test case correctly.

here is my spec code

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'users rake tasks' do
  before do
    Rake.application.rake_require 'tasks/users'
    Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  end

  context 'when remove credential state users who no longer request for confirm otp within 10 minutes' do
    let(:user) { create(:user, last_otp_at: Time.now - 11.minutes, state: "credentials") }
    let (:run_users_rake_task) do
      Rake.application.invoke_task 'users:failed_user_cleaner'
    end

    it 'calls right service method' do
      @users = Users::Delete.new([user])
      expect(@users).to receive(:destroy_all)

      run_users_rake_task
    end
  end
end
```

here is the error log

Failures:

```
  1) users rake tasks when remove credential state users who no longer request for confirm otp within 10 minutes calls right service method
 Failure/Error: expect(@users).to receive(:destroy_all)
 
   (#<Users::Delete:0x0000556dfcca3a40 @user=[#<User id: 181, uuid: nil, phone: "+66969597538", otp_secret: nil, last_otp_at: "2021-09-30 09:32:24.961548000 +0700", created_at: "2021-09-30 09:43:24.973818000 +0700", updated_at: "2021-09-30 09:43:24.973818000 +0700", email: nil, avatar: "https://dummyimage.com/300x300/f04720/153572.png?t...", refresh_token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MzI5Njk4MDQsImV4c...", first_name_en: "Jenise", first_name_th: "Damion", last_name_en: "McCullough", last_name_th: "Beatty", nationality: "TH", thai_national_id: nil, thai_laser_code: nil, company_id: 200, role: nil, state: "credentials", date_of_birth: "2020-10-30 00:00:00.000000000 +0700", deleted_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$jfR9X9ci06602tlAyLOoRewTK1lZ12vJ2cZ9Dc2ov4F...", username: "zreejme238", shopname: nil, access_token: nil, locked_at: nil, login_attempts: 0, locale: "th", scorm_completed: false>]>).destroy_all(*(any args))
       expected: 1 time with any arguments
       received: 0 times with any arguments
 # ./spec/tasks/users_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two instances of `Users::Delete` when running this test, one within the test and one within the task. Since the instance within the test is not used, it is incorrect to expect it to receive a message.

Rspec has an expectation, [expect_any_instance_of](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance#use-%60expect-any-instance-of%60-to-set-a-message-expectation-on-any-instance), that will fix this however consider reading the full page since it can create fragile or flaky tests. If you wanted to use this method, your test would look something like:

```rb
it 'calls right service method' do
  expect_any_instance_of(Users::Delete).to receive(:destroy_all)

  run_users_rake_task
end
```

Personally I'd instead check that the expected users were deleted with something like:

```rb
it 'removes the user' do
  expect { run_users_rake_task }.to change { User.exists?(id: @user.id) }.to(false)
end
```

Comment: can you like my question?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use `any_instance_of` (which is a code smell) you need to stub the `Users::Delete` method so that it returns a double and put the expectation on the double:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'users rake tasks' do
  before do
    Rake.application.rake_require 'tasks/users'
    Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  end

  context 'when remove credential state users who no longer request for confirm otp within 10 minutes' do
    let(:user) { create(:user, last_otp_at: Time.now - 11.minutes, state: "credentials") }
    let(:run_users_rake_task) do
      Rake.application.invoke_task 'users:failed_user_cleaner'
    end

    let(:double) do
       instance_double('Users::Delete') 
    end

    before do
      allow(Users::Delete).to receive(:new).and_return(double)
    end

    it 'calls right service method' do
      expect(double).to receive(:destroy_all)
      run_users_rake_task
    end
  end
end
```

However this really just tells us that the API of the service object is clunky and that you should write a class method which both instanciates and performs:

```
module Users
  class Delete
    # ...
    def self.destroy_all(users)
      new(users).destroy_all
    end
  end
end
```

```
desc 'Remove credential state users who no longer request for confirm otp within 10 minutes'
 #...

 Users::Delete.destroy_all(@user)

 # ...
end
```

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'users rake tasks' do
  # ...
  context 'when remove credential state users who no longer request for confirm otp within 10 minutes' do
    # ...
    it 'calls right service method' do
      expect(Users::Delete).to receive(:destroy_all)
      run_users_rake_task
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If I use Users::Delete(@user).destroy_all, I can't delete multiple users at once due to causing issue.  so I am going to call `.destroy_call` method at the end of @users. like this  `User.with_state("credentials").with_last_otp_at(Time.now - 10.minutes).destroy_all` from .rake file.  in this case, How can I write the unit test?  I hope your help for it

Comment: @CaTs excellent answer has an example of testing the actual behavior instead of the implementation. Use it.